# Regex for last match of string in last group

Tags: regex

I have following string.

`SO 01 053 675 A2`

And Here I need

`SO` to be in Group 1 (Group 1 can have at most 2 characters).

`01 053 675` in Group 2. (Group 2 can have space, comma, forward slash, dot, dash)

`A2` in Group 3 (Group 3 can have one alphabet at most and one number at most).

And above groups are seperated by space and/or dash or without seperator.

I have prepared following.

```
^([A-Z|a-z]{2})*[-|\s]*([A-Z]{0,2}[\d|,|\/|.]+)*[-|\s]*([A-Z]?[\d]?)
```

Now above regex works as far as Group 2 doesn't have space.

e.g. `WO 01.053/675 A2`

But it doesn't work with space in Group 2 even if I add space in 2nd group in regex.

e.g. `WO 01 053 675 A2`

How can I fix this regex?

Below I have added sample. You can see that A2 doesn't map to Group 3 at all when space is there.

https://regex101.com/r/6FceHh/1

Following are all sample string which requires support as individual solution is breaking other things.

In following case `OK` should go in Group 1. Middle string should go in Group 2. Last string `A1` should go in Group 3.

```
'OK-' // Here Group 2 and Group 3 will be empty.
'OK-AB1234-A1'
'OK-1234-A1'
'OK-112-223-A1'
'OK 112 223 A1'
'OKB1A1'
'OKBB1A1'
'OK112223A1' // Here no separator is present.
'112.223' // Here Group 1 and Group 3 will be empty.
'112 223' // Here Group 1 and Group 3 will be empty.
```

Comment: Does `^([A-Za-z]{2})[-\s]+(.*?)[-\s]+([A-Z]\d)$` work for you?

Comment: Or perhaps `^([A-Za-z]{2})[ -]([A-Z\d\/,.-]+(?:[ -][A-Z\d\/,.-]+)*)[ -]([A-Z]\d)$` https://regex101.com/r/9hclJK/1

Comment: Hi Folks seems trying one solution is breaking another one. I have attached sample string in question that I need to support.

Comment: In some cases separator won't be present as well.

Comment: You can try like this with three optional groups: [`^\b([A-Za-z]{2})?([ \w.\/-]+?)?([A-Za-z]\d)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/uZxmgF/1) It looks like your group two also can contain digits and letters btw.

Comment: @bobblebubble. Perfect man. Its working in all conditions. I have updated it a bit to satisfy all my conditions. But that was the main issue. I was having * of group instead of ? of group. Here is the full updated regex you can put in your answer. `^([A-Za-z]{2})?[- ]*([A-Z]{0,2}[\d,\/. -]+[\d])?[- ]*([A-Z]\d?)?`

Comment: @AnonymousCreator Your update of my regex does not match e.g. `OKB1A1`... I'm not clear about the exact requirements. Please post the working solution yourself.

Comment: This is it. Middle group needed * `^([A-Za-z]{2})?[- ]*([A-Z]{0,2}[\d,\/. -]*[\d])?[- ]*([A-Z]\d?)?`

Comment: @AnonymousCreator Looks good. And you don't want the `\b` at start to disallow empty matches? ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/j7LgfX/1)) Let me know if you answer yourself or expect me to put the answer :p

Comment: @bobblebubble. Please post as answer. I don't want to take credit of your solution :)

Comment: I am fine without \b as I need to keep all groups as empty value in case doesn't match. So.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using three *optional groups* with any `[- ]` separator in between turned out to work.

```
^\b([A-Za-z]{2})?[- ]*([A-Z]{0,2}[\d,\/. -]*\d)?[- ]*([A-Z]\d?)?
```

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j7LgfX/2) - The `\b` [word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) will prevent empty matches.

Comment: That `^\b` is pretty clever when all is optional but the string should start with a word character. Something to remember!

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, OP does [not seem to want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938438/regex-for-last-match-of-string-in-last-group/74940208?noredirect=1#comment132246386_74938438) my `\b`, but I wanted to have it mentioned! He will take it out and have his empty matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: [`^(\w{2})\s(.*)\s(\w{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/3gMR1y/1)

- Matches the first segment / 2 characters: `(\w{2})`
- Everything in the middle: `(.*)`
- And the last 2 characters: `(\w{2})`

Comment: In some cases space won't be present. So this will not work in that case. I have added all test strings for example of grouping.